# DeadlineExceededError workarounds

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm making something like a web spider.
It will catch the data i want form the WEB LIST.
The amount of the WEB LIST is approximately 20.
Each can de done around 1 to 10 seconds.

I know `DeadlineExceededError` means my request handler didn't finish within 30 seconds.
I also know that I can't change the 30 second limit.

So I need to split my job into into small pieces but I don't know how to do that.

Here is my code:

```
    List<String> ids = agent.getWebList();

    if(ids.iterator().hasNext()) {
        for(String id : ids) {
            Data d = agent.getDetailedDataById(id);
            agent.updateData(d);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If it wasn't GAE, using threads and interrupting them just before reaching the limit would be the best solution. If it wasn't GAE...

Comment: Thanks, maybe I can use it next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working on a web spider the best approach is to use task queues:

[Java Task Queue docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview.html)

[Python Task Queue docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html)

Comment: I agree, and for ease of reference since this was a Java question, here is the Task Queue for Java overview: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview.html

Comment: The time limit for task queues, as of API 1.4.0, is 10 minutes.

Comment: @Travis Webb , the limit is for a one task isnt it? in this scenario url from the WEB LIST. since it only takes around 1 to 10 seconds it will be ok i think.

Comment: I know why i miss it. Google don't translate it in Chinese Google doc. I will try it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

While iterating through your ids, keep a counter. When you catch the DeadLineExceededError, pass the counter as argument to the task which starts processing from that position. This will be done sequentially. You can also split the job and give to several tasks to process at same time.

Answer (score 0):

Two `DeadlineExceededError`s are raised. You can catch it the first time, and tidy up your state ready to continue again later or spawning a task for the next stage.

You can not catch `DeadlineExceededError` the second time.

Comment: Could you explain what is "Two DeadlineExceededErrors are raised".
Or I miss something I should know on the document. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using task queue which have execution time of 10 mins, the first deadline exceeded error(soft) is thrown around 10 mins which can be caught. 
The second one is the hard deadline limit which cannot be caught and ur task is terminated by GAE.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. I think I can get it done in these way.